# Query rows as columns ( MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

My table structure:

```
cust_id | action   | action_count
--------+----------+-------------
1       | Approved | 15
2       | Approved | 25
1       | Rejected | 6
2       | Pending  | 20
2       | Rejected | 7
```

I have to get the query result as:

```
cust_id | Approved | Pending | Rejected
--------+----------+---------+---------
1       | 15       | 0       | 6
2       | 25       | 20      | 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query

```
select 
   cust_id, 
   max(if(action='Approved', action_count, 0)) as Approved,
   max(if(action='Rejected', action_count, 0)) as Rejected,
   max(if(action='Pending', action_count, 0)) as Pending
from 
   tbl
group by 
   cust_id
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba4ef/1)**

```
| CUST_ID | APPROVED | REJECTED | PENDING |
-------------------------------------------
|       1 |       15 |        6 |       0 |
|       2 |       25 |        7 |      20 |
```

Comment: +1 and well played @Meherzad - beat me by about 10 seconds :)

Comment: Thank you @Meherzad, your query helped me. I solved it using SUM(), instead of max().

Comment: You can use any aggregate function which you want according to your need of query ..

Comment: @Meherzad, I want to sort the columns in descending order of APPROVED column. How to achieve this. Please help me..

Answer (score 4):

Here's a static query if the number of `action` is known.

```
SELECT  cust_id,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'Approved' THEN action_Count END), 0) Approved,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'Pending ' THEN action_Count END), 0) Pending ,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'Rejected' THEN action_Count END), 0) Rejected 
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY cust_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e337d/5)

But if the number of value of `action` is unknown, a dynamic sql is much more preferred.

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN action = ''',
               action,
               ''' THEN action_Count END), 0) AS ',
               CONCAT('`', action, '`')
               )) INTO @sql
FROM TableName;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT   cust_id, ', @sql, ' 
                    FROM    TableName
                    GROUP   BY cust_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e337d/4)